# TypeScript creat recursive typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Example because its not easy to explain

i need this to query data from database typeorm does not support it, so i need a way to generate cool typing, please help me

```js
export class CategoryEntity {

  id: string;

  name: string;

  parentId?: CategoryEntity;
}


export class SpecialEntity {
  id: string;

  category: CategoryEntity;
}
```

resulting type should be

```js
{ 
  id?: "ASC" | "DESC",
  category?: {
    id?: "ASC" | "DESC"
    name?: "ASC" | "DESC"
    parentId?: {
       id?: "ASC" | "DESC"
       name?: "ASC" | "DESC"
       parentId?: {
         ...
       }
    }
  }
}
```

should be used like

```js
const order: OrderRelation<SpecificEntity> = {
  category: {
    parentId: {
      name: 'ASC'
    }
  }
}
```

Thx for helping me

Comment: Is this question specific to typeorm?  If so, you should probably tag it as such.  If not, please consider removing references to it in your code so that it is a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WvVY4W).  Right now I can't even begin to look at this without trying to figure out where to import these third-party decorators from, or removing the decorators, etc.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wybbnw) meet your needs?  Please check against your use cases and let me know.